# nexus-repository-apk v0.0.26 plugin is it compatible with Nexus Repository PRO Version 3.61.0-02

Tags: nexus3

Is nexus-repository-apk v0.0.26 plugin is it compatible with Nexus Repository PRO Version 3.61.0-02

There is a opensource community forum page https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-apk/tree/master which maintain this plugin, can someone confirm whether this plugin requires any change to work against Nexus Repository PRO Version 3.61.0-02+

Trying to install plugin in the Nexus Repository PRO and it is not showing up in the proxy repository creation